# FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever returns setDataSource failed: status = > 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

This is a weird error! because it sometimes works but sometimes doesn't work. I'm using [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) to get the thumbnail from a video using an URL path. `retriever.setDataSource(((Video) obj).getVideoAddress());` return following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status =
>   0xFFFFFFFF

**This is my code:**

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            Bitmap bmp;

            retriever.setDataSource(((Video) obj).getVideoAddress
                    ());

            bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
```

**Note:** I checked the INTERNET permission and it exists. The problem is exists with some videos but with the same format! I mean the only difference between videos is bit rates, length, size and others like this but not the file format.

Comment: Same happens to me, no error on experia device but the above issue happens on galaxy s6.